# Main class for jar file missing for Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have been trying to execute a jar file ssr.runner, jar using task with type `JavaExec`. But gradle is giving me the error that `no main class specified`. I am new to gradle so if any one could please elaborate in detail that would be great. Here is the task that I wrote:

```
task executeSqlScriptRunnerBeforeTenantCreation(type:JavaExec) {
    description "Execute ssr.runner to install certificates into the device"
    doLast {
        if(scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_INTERSECT_MOCK') == 'true') {

            println "Executing SQL Script Runner..."
            println "Adding certificates for mocked intersect service"

            if(scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_TYPE') == 'SQL_SERVER') {
                classpath =  file("{$workingDir}\\ssr.runner.jar")
                main =  '-jar' 
                args '-dbtype', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_TYPE')}", '-dbhost', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_HOST')}", '-dbinstance', 
                "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_INSTANCE')}", '-dbname', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_NAME')}", '-dbuser', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_USER')}",
                '-dbpass', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_PASS')}", '-sqlscriptpath', "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_INTERSECT_MOCK_DB_SCRIPT')}"  
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your jar has in it's manifest.mf file a value for Main-Class, which is used to find a main class to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're mixing two phases: *execution* and *configuration*. There's no need to add `doLast` for predefined tasks. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/potential_traps.html#sec:configuration_and_execution_phase). Then this is (probably) how the script should look like:

```
task executeSqlScriptRunnerBeforeTenantCreation(type:JavaExec) {
    description "Execute ssr.runner to install certificates into the device"

    if(scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_INTERSECT_MOCK') == 'true') {
        println "Configuring SQL Script Runner..."
        println "Adding certificates for mocked intersect service"

        if(scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_TYPE') == 'SQL_SERVER') {
            main = '<FULLY QUALIFIED NAME OF CLASS YOU NEED TO RUN>' 
            classpath =  file("{$workingDir}\\ssr.runner.jar")            
            args '-dbtype', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_TYPE')}", 
                 '-dbhost', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_HOST')}", 
                 '-dbinstance', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_INSTANCE')}", 
                 '-dbname', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_NAME')}", 
                 '-dbuser', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_USER')}",
                 '-dbpass', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_DB_PASS')}", 
                 '-sqlscriptpath', 
                 "${scriptRunnerVariables.get('SSR_INTERSECT_MOCK_DB_SCRIPT')}"  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`main` was misconfigured there should be a fully qualified (with package) name of java class you need to run passed. Of course, what is *configured* via `classpath`, `main`, `args` and so on in *configuration* phase will be *run* in *execution* phase only if the two expressions in `if` block evaluate to true.